# Sequelize attribute with alias seems undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get `id` of AttributeValue model with an alias of `attribute_value_id` as below but `attribute_value_id` seems `undefined` in `otherOptions` constant.

```
const otherOptions = await AttributeValue.findAll({
  where: { 
    id: { 
     [Op.in]: attributeValueIds
     } },
  attributes: [
    ['id', 'attribute_value_id'],
    'attribute_id',
    'value'
  ]
})
```

I'm fallowing [sequlize documantation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) about querying and the below query is built by sequelize but there is no alias attribute in the resulting object.

```
SELECT `id` AS `attribute_value_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM `attribute_values` AS `attribute_value` WHERE `attribute_value`.`id` IN (1, 1, 1, 1, 19);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with `otherOptions[0].getDataValue('attribute_value_id')`